# How to use multiple Pagination class in one view in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework, pagination

I want to create a web server that it used by mobile clients and web clients. Web client developer wants `limit offset pagination` but mobile client developer wants `page number pagination`.

In django rest framework seems we can not assign multiple pagination class to one view.

so is there any solution in this situation?

Answer (score 4):

Based on Vikram Ray's answer:

```
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings


class MultiplePaginationMixin:

    def get_pagination_class(self):
        return self.pagination_class
    
    @property
    def paginator(self):
        """The paginator instance associated with the view, or `None`."""
        pagination_class = self.get_pagination_class()
        if not hasattr(self, '_paginator'):
            if pagination_class is None:
                self._paginator = None
            else:
                self._paginator = pagination_class()
        return self._paginator
```

Now you can use it without braces:

```
class MyView(MultiplePaginationMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def get_pagination_class(self):
        if some_codition:
            return PageNumberPagination
        return api_settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS
```

Comment: Really elegant. Nicely done!

Answer (score 2):

simpley use property() function.

```
class MyView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_pagination_class(self):
        if some_codition:
           return PageNumberPagination
        return LimitOffsetPagination
    pagination_class = property(fget=get_pagination_class)
```

that's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Initially create a mixin class,

```
class MultiplePaginationMixin:
    def get_pagination_class(self):
        return self.pagination_class

    @property
    def paginator(self):
        pagination_class = self.get_pagination_class()
        if pagination_class is None:
            return None
        return pagination_class()
```

and use it in your view by overriding the **`get_pagination_class(...)`** method as,

```
class MyView(MultiplePaginationMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_pagination_class(self):
        if some_codition:
            return PageNumberPagination
        return LimitOffsetPagination
```